# I have written a code that I cannot seem to get working

Tags: java

I am having trouble getting my code to work. The purpose is for the method created to reverse the integer number that has been input. And at the bottom is the test code to test the method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseDigit
{
   public void reverseDigits()
   {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(system.in);
       {
           System.out.print( "Please enter an integer number (other than -999 unless you wish to exit):");
           number = input.nextInt();

           while ( number != -999 )
           {
              System.out.printf( "%d reversed is %d\n", number, reverseDigits( number ) );

              System.out.print( "Enter an integer (-1 to exit): " );
              number = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
   }
   public int reverseDigits ( int number);
   {
      int reverseNumber = 0; 
      int placeValue; 

      while ( number > 0 )
      {
          placeValue = number % 10;
          number = number / 10;
          reversedNumbers = reversedNumbers * 10 + placeValue;
       }
       return reversedNumbers; 
    }
}
public class ReverseDigitsActive
{
   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
       Reverse application = new Reverse();
       application.reverseDigit();
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is input and what is output and what is not working ?

Comment: You should try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @CrazyNinja No he shouldn't. Codereview is not for fixing broken code.

Comment: Thanks all who helped me with this, and to all who criticized my code. I am new to coding so any and all helpful comments are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your class to something like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseDigit
{
   public void reverseDigits()
 {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print( "Please enter an integer number (other than -999 unless you wish to exit):");
     int number = input.nextInt();

     do
     {
        System.out.printf( "%d reversed is %d\n",
        number, toReverseDigits( number ) );

        System.out.print( "Enter an integer (-1 to exit): " );
        number = input.nextInt();

     }while(number>-1)


  }
     public int toReverseDigits ( int number)
     {
        int reverseNumber = 0; 
        int placeValue; 

        while ( number > 0 )
        {
           placeValue = number % 10;
           number = number / 10;
           reverseNumber = reverseNumber * 10 + placeValue;
        }
        return reverseNumber; 
     }
  }
  public class ReverseDigitsActive
  {
     public static void main( String args[] )
     {
        ReverseDigit application = new ReverseDigit();
        application.reverseDigits();
     }
  }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: When you fix OPs code, then also explain what you've done.

Comment: Thanks for the help, after comparing yours with mine and checking the book I was able to get the code running as desired.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any IDE to run this application, you should get many errors in this code.

1. The first mistake is in line 4 where you should use `System` (not *"system"*).
2. The second mistake is, you are using `number` variable without declaring it in **line 6**.
3. You don't have any declaration for the variable `reversedNumbers` in **line 31**.
4. You are using class name `Reverse` which does not exists in the current context in **line 40**.
5. You have also used `reverseDigit()` method in **line 41** which also does not exists.

---

The code given by Aradhna is working for your reference and if you wanna exit the program when user input is -1 then the code is follows,

```
System.out.print( "Enter an integer (-1 to exit): " );
    number = input.nextInt();
if (number == -1)
    break;
```

Comment: Any comment for negative point..because I am still learning and don't want to do that mistake again.. :-)

Comment: I don't understand the down vote.. here take my up.

Comment: Still learning for formatting..Anyway thanks for the edit @Tom

Comment: Then this help page might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the help all.  And I was using jgrasp if someone recommends something else feel free.